# Mock result from Func with NSubstitute

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nsubstitute

I'm trying to use NSubstitute to mock the return value from a Substitute, but I cannot get the substitute to return the correct value because the method signature is using a Func.

I've seen these questions, but cannot make it work with my Func.

[Mocking Action<T> with NSubstitute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29300512/mocking-actiont-with-nsubstitute)

[Mocking out expression with NSubstitute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26120821/mocking-out-expression-with-nsubstitute)

The interface I try to mock is this (somewhat simplyfied):

```
public interface IOrgTreeRepository<out T> where T : IHierarchicalUnit
{
    T FirstOrDefault(Func<T, bool> predicate);
}
```

I'm substituting it with NSubstitute like so:

```
_orgTreeRepository = Substitute.For<IOrgTreeRepository<IOrganizationUnit>>();
```

And then I try to change the return value like so:

```
_orgTreeRepository.FirstOrDefault(Arg.Is<Func<IOrganizationUnit, bool>>(x => x.Id== _itemsToUpdate[0].Id)).Returns(existingItems[0]);
```

But it simply returns a proxy-object instead of my defined object in *existingItems*.

However, thanks to the other questions I managed to get this to work, but it does not help me, since I need a specific item every time.

```
_orgTreeRepository.FirstOrDefault(Arg.Any<Func<IOrganizationUnit, bool>>()).Returns(existingItems[0]); // Semi-working
```

I guess it's treating the lambda expression as a kind of absolute reference and therefore skips it? Is there any way I can mock the return value?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As you correctly guessed, NSubstitute just uses reference equality here, so unless you have a reference to the same predicate (which is sometimes an option) then you'll have to match any call (`Arg.Any` or `.ReturnsForAnyArgs`) or use an approximate form of matching to check the function passed in.

An example of approximate matching:

```
[Test]
public void Foo() {
    var sample = new Record("abc");
    var sub = Substitute.For<IOrgTreeRepository<Record>>();
    sub.FirstOrDefault(Arg.Is<Func<Record,bool>>(f => f(sample))).Returns(sample);

    Assert.AreSame(sample, sub.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id.StartsWith ("a")));
    Assert.AreSame(sample, sub.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == "abc"));
    Assert.Null(sub.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == "def"));
}
```

Here we've stubbed `FirstOrDefault` to return `sample` whenever the `Func<T,bool>` returns `true` for `sample` (this is using a different overload of `Arg.Is` which takes an expression, rather than the value of the argument passed in).

This passes the test for two different predicates, because `sample` satisfies both of them. It also passes the last assertion, in that it doesn't return `sample` for a func that checks for a different id. We can't guarantee a specific predicate was used in this case, but it might be enough. Otherwise we're stuck with reference quality on the Func.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Well, that's an excellent solution to my problem. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I would have never guessed that ! Thank you a lot.